# DBSCAN algorithm (recursion logic)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dbscan

```
DBSCAN(D, eps, MinPts)
   C = 0
   for each unvisited point P in dataset D
      mark P as visited
      NeighborPts = regionQuery(P, eps)
      if sizeof(NeighborPts) < MinPts
         mark P as NOISE
      else
         C = next cluster
         expandCluster(P, NeighborPts, C, eps, MinPts)

expandCluster(P, NeighborPts, C, eps, MinPts)
   add P to cluster C
   for each point P' in NeighborPts 
      if P' is not visited
         mark P' as visited
         NeighborPts' = regionQuery(P', eps)
         if sizeof(NeighborPts') >= MinPts
            NeighborPts = NeighborPts joined with NeighborPts'
      if P' is not yet member of any cluster
         add P' to cluster C

regionQuery(P, eps)
   return all points within P's eps-neighborhood
```

Above is. as you can see, the algorithm  of DBSCAN according to Wikipedia.

I want to ask about this exact part.

```
      NeighborPts = NeighborPts joined with NeighborPts'
```

My understanding was that if a core point from a neighbor of core point is visited, it will be joined to the currently examined cluster, right? But how does the recursion happen here? Because we has defined the loop of:

```
   for each point P' in NeighborPts
```

before the process of the joining, so any additional point from NeighborPts' won't be examined by the expandCluster function and if the new NeighborPts' actually has a point that is an another core point to the same cluster, how does the algorithm proceed?

I have a code with the implementation of 'expandCluster' method in Java:

```
public void expand(Vector<Integer> region, Group c, double dist, int minPts){
    for(int i = 0; i < region.size(); i++){
        int idx = region.get(i);
        if(labels[idx] == 0){                         // check if point is visited
            labels[idx] = 1;                          // mark as visited
            Vector<Integer> v = region(idx, dist);    // check for neighboring point
            if (v.size() >= minPts){                  // check if core point
                region.addAll(v);                     // join the NeighborPts 
            }
        }
        if(clustered[idx] == 0){
            c.elements.add(patterns.get(idx));
            clustered[idx] = clusters.size()+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Will the data collection `region` going to be revisited after the modification of the data collection through this code `region.addAll(v);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding was that if a core point from a neighbor of core
>   point is visited, it will be joined to the currently examined cluster,
>   right?

Yes you're right and you can safely remove the line

> if P' is not visited

However, this is not efficient.

If a point P' has been visited there is no need to compute its neighborhood and join it with the neighborhood of P.

It is visited means that: it's a noise point, it is already in a cluster or it's a border point.
If it's already in a cluster and if it's a core point, this means that its neighbors have been processed already.
If it's a border point then its neighbors must not be joined.

> But how does the recursion happen here?

In the line

> for each point P' in NeighborPts

you must consider `NeighborPts` as a dynamic container of points. The first time you enter the for loop `NeighborPts` contains `X` points. If the joining adds `Y` points to `NeighborPts` then the for loop will visit both `X` and `Y` sets. This will then repeat for the sets `X` and `Y` and this is how the recursion happens.

> Will the data collection region going to be revisited after the
>   modification of the data collection through this code
>   region.addAll(v);?

Yes, every time you call `region.addAll(v)`, `region.size()` increases and this confirms the recursion behavior that confuses you.

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't know that `addAll()` can produce this kind of behavior and it made me so confused on the recursion.